# How to overcome javascript array iteration skipping record/s

Tags: javascript, arrays, firefox, safari

Having a problem, which occurs in Firefox and Safari, but in Chrome it works fine.

This javascript array contains quiz questions, which I display one at at a time. However, sometimes not all records are iterated. I used the console, and it is definitely loading all questions, but still sometimes skips a record (usually only the first one).

**EDIT:** I have noticed that on quizes this array works for, all questionids are in order, i.e 290,291,293 in the array. But in in an example of one not working, the quiz id's are in this order, 286,285,287,288 and 285 is the one that is skipped, this could be part of the problem.

Here is my Javascript array code, please help me solve this problem.

```
var currentquestion;

        jQuery.ajax({
                    url:"quizajax.php",


        dataType: "json",
                data: { 
                    quizidvalue: <?=$thisquizid?>
                },
        }).done(function(data) {
                questions = data;
                for(i in data){
                    console.log(data[i]);

                }
            });

function nextQuestion (){
        for(i in questions) {
            if(i<=currentquestion)
                continue;

            currentquestion = i;

            for(y in questions[i]) {
                console.log("CurrentA: "+ currentquestion);
                console.log("I: " + i);
                console.log(questions[i][y].answerid);
            }
            console.log("CurrentQ: "+ currentquestion);
            console.log("I: " + i);
            console.log(questions[i]);
            questionVariables ();
            break;
        }
```

Example code from db,

```
 questionid | quizid | questiontype |   qdescription   |           qfilelocation            | noofanswers | answertype 
------------+--------+--------------+------------------+------------------------------------+-------------+------------
        285 |     55 | text         | 6 answer text    | null                               |           6 | text
        287 |     55 | text         | 4ans text q      | null                               |           4 | text
        289 |     55 | text         | 2 answers text q | null                               |           2 | text
        286 |     55 | text         | 5 answer text q  | null                               |           5 | text
        288 |     55 | text         | 3 answer text q  | null                               |           3 | text
        290 |     55 | image        | image q and a    | image/55/712013a88298585d415c.jpeg |           4 | image
        291 |     55 | video        | video q and a    | video/55/8efa10195f0c20d1254f.mp4  |           4 | video
```

Comment: hi - where is `currentquestion` initialised?

Comment: as a global variable. var currentquestion = 0;

Comment: if i == 0, it will skip current question == 0

Comment: As your suggestion I am now initialising as var currentquestion; Still having the problem in FF and Safari though

Comment: is questions an array? can you post sample data

Comment: edited post with sample code, and some new info I discovered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `continue` statement is causing the loop to skip part of its execution.
Try debugging so see where code logic has the bug.

```
    for(i in questions) {
        if(i<=currentquestion) {
            console.log('Skipping question: ' + i); // add debugging
            continue;
        }
        ...
```

**EDIT:** (several comments based on update)

1. Its best to iterate through arrays using traditional for loops:

   ```
   for (var i = 0, len = questions.length; i < len; i++) {
   ```

   But the outer loop isnt event needed
2. If you initialize `var currentquestion = 0;` the outer loop can be replaced

   ```
   function nextQuestion (){

       for(y in questions[currentquestion]) {
           console.log("CurrentA: "+ currentquestion);
           console.log(questions[currentquestion][y].answerid);
       }
       console.log("CurrentQ: "+ currentquestion);
       console.log(questions[currentquestion]);
       questionVariables ();
       currentquestion++; //update here
   }
   ```
3. It looks like your code depends on order, so you can sort

   ```
   .done(function(data) {
       questions = data;
       questions.sort(function(q1,q2){

       //assuming questionid is the correct property
           if (q1.questionid < q2.questionid) {
               return -1;
           } else if (q1.questionid > q2.questionid) {
               return 1;
           }
           return 0; 
       });
       ...
   ```
4. You could have used `jquery.getJSON` or `$.ajax( { success ....})`
5. You should probably reset `currentquestion = 0;` in your done method.

Comment: Found some new info while using javascript console, it's in the edit part of my original post. Thanks for your help so far

Comment: I managed to get it working, and your solution helped, thanks